# Socket Error - Sending email using gmail

Tags: python, smtp

I am using the code from [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Send_an_email#Python) article to send an email using gmail.

The code is as follows

```
import smtplib

def sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,
          subject, message,
          login, password,
          smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587'):
    header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
    header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
    header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
    header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
    message = header + message

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login,password)
    problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
    server.quit()
    return problems
```

When i run it, I however get the following socket error.

```
socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

EDIT: Traceback

```
O:\Send Email With Attachment>SendEmail_Ver2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "O:\Send Email With Attachment\SendEmail_Ver2.py", line 26, in <module>
password     = 'XXXXXXXXXXX')
File "O:\SendEmail_Ver2.py", line 13, in sendemail
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 561, in create_connection
raise error, msg socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in   
a way forbidden by its access permissions`
```

How do I get privileges for the script to use port 587? Or is there a higher port number that gmail can use?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give us the traceback instead of just the error string?

Comment: How about using default port, smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com'?

Comment: I tried your code above and received a email with no error

Comment: @abarnert I have added the Traceback

Comment: Just tried it with Python 27 and same issue.

Comment: @David.Zheng I get the same error with the default port

Comment: Bizarre. The MSDN docs on [WSAEACCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) and the function Python suggest things like UDP broadcast or explicitly binding a local address, but you're not doing anything like that. I can't imagine how you'd get this problem without a system so screwed up you couldn't reach the internet. You're going to need to do some debugging and report the results. Let me come up with a few things for you to try.

Comment: Wait a second… Maybe IPv6 is broken, but not IPv4. In an interactive interpreter, `import socket`, then try three things: `s = socket.socket(); s.connect(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))`, `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6); s.connect(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))`. Finally, `s = socket.create_connection(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))`. If the first one works and the others both give you that 10013 error, the problem is that your name server prefers IPv6, but you don't have the rights to use IPv6, so we can figure out how to work around that. And if that's not what happens… well, at least we'll know more.

Comment: @abarnert Here is what I get
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(); s.connect(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(); s.connect(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: >>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6); s.connect(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6); s.connect(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: >>> s = socket.create_connection(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    s = socket.create_connection(('smtp.gmail.com', 587))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: Even the first one failed? What about `s.connect(('www.google.com', 80))`? Also, can you open a DOS prompt and try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` (to find out whether it's specific to Python, or other programs have the same problem)?

Comment: s.connect(('www.google.com', 80)) worked

Comment: C:\>telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 58
7: Connect failed

Comment: @abarnert So, it looks like its not specific to Python?

Comment: OK, if something is wrong with your system or your network, you'll need to find a site where people can help you with Windows or LAN problems, like maybe [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 9):

The problem was McAfee Antivirus. It was blocking the socket connection.

From McAfee Access Protection Log

> 23/08/2013 10:23:54 a.m.   Blocked by port blocking rule   C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\python.exe  Anti-virus Standard Protection:Prevent mass mailing worms from sending mail 74.125.25.108:25

I disabled McAfee completely and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 8):

The problem for me was also McAfee.  But instead of disabling McAfee completely as user1494941 did, I would recommend adding python.exe to the list of excepted programs:

In the VirusScan Console,

1. Right-click on 'Access Protection', select 'Properties'
2. In Categories, Select 'Anti-virus Standard Protection'
3. In the Rules panel, select 'Prevent mass mailing worms from sending email'
4. Select 'Edit', to edit the rules for this protection.
5. Add python.exe to the list of processes to exclude and then OK.